# How do I remove a phrase that is added to product title in Woo-commerce

Tags: wordpress

I am using entrada theme on Wordpress for a tour website. It has a "All tour page". When I click on load more on the Tour listing page, it adds "with details" to the product title.

I have added a replace function to the functions file but it doesn't work

```
add_filter( 'gettext', 'theme_change_field_names', 20, 3 );
function theme_change_field_names( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {



        switch ( $translated_text ) {

            case 'with detail' :

                $translated_text = __( '', 'theme_text_domain' );
                break;


        }



    return $translated_text;
}
```

Please how can I remove the with details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better of course to find where 'with detail' is added. Try the hook, should help solve this display problem:

```
`remove_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title','woocommerce_template_loop_product_title',10);
add_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title','change_product_title',10);
function change_product_title()
{
   echo str_replace('with detail', "", "get_the_title()");
}`
```